# JavaFX application showing an empty stage for a fraction of a second before a scene embedded with gif starts in a slow system?

Tags: java, javafx-8, animated-gif, preloader

We have a scene that has opacity = 0 initially and gradually increases the opacity = 1 for a nice and smooth fade-in animation. But when the scene is added to a stage, in slow systems, the stage is shown with opacity = 1 for a fraction of a second before the actual scene animation starts from opacity 0. This causes an initial blinking effect.

[image]

The code for creating the preloader is given below:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    initializeJavaFxApplicationThread();
    stage.setTitle(CommonConstants.APPLICATION_NAME);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    CommonUiHelper.addApplicationIconToWindow(stage);
    loadPreloaderScene(stage);
}

private void loadPreloaderScene(Stage stage) {
    if (isTwoStepPreLoaderAllowed()) {
         log.log(Level.INFO, "Using 2-step preloader");
         stage.setScene(createPreloaderGifAnimationScene());
         runPreloaderScreenWithDelay(stage);
    } else {
         log.log(Level.INFO, "Using single-step preloader");
         stage.setScene(createPreloaderScene());
         preloaderPresenter.doFadeIn();
    }
    stage.show();
 }
private Scene createPreloaderScene() {
    PreloaderView preloaderView = new PreloaderView();
    preloaderPresenter = preloaderView.getRealPresenter();
     return new Scene(preloaderView.getView(), LOADING_SCREEN_WIDTH,   LOADING_SCREEN_HEIGHT, Color.TRANSPARENT);
  }
private Scene createPreloaderGifAnimationScene() {
    PreloaderGifAnimationView preloaderGifAnimationView = new PreloaderGifAnimationView();
    preloaderGifAnimationPresenter = preloaderGifAnimationView.getRealPresenter();
    return new Scene(preloaderGifAnimationView.getView(), LOADING_SCREEN_WIDTH, LOADING_SCREEN_HEIGHT, Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

private void runPreloaderScreenWithDelay(Stage stage) {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
          Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if (!applicationLoadedStatus) {
              stage.setScene(createPreloaderScene());
              stage.show();
            }
          });
          }
        };
       Timer timer = new Timer("PRELOADER_TIMER");
       timer.schedule(task, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(9500));
  }

public static boolean isTwoStepPreLoaderAllowed() {
    final LocalTime allowedTime = LocalTime.of(11, 30);
    if (PlatformUtil.getBooleanSystemProperty("enableFastBoot"))     {
      return false;
     }
  return LocalTime.now().isBefore(allowedTime);
 }
```

Comment: [Format code before you post](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html), it is hard to explain how disappointing it is when somebody puts so little effort into a question and expects an answer.

Comment: Usually it is best (and certainly in this case), to post a [mcve].  Something that could be copy and pasted to reproduce the issue.  Make sure it is minimal (doesn't include *any* unneeded code) and complete (no missing classes or unresolved variables).